# Java API shows an example which instantiates interface

Tags: java, interface, anonymous-function, anonymous-class

I am aware that a Java interface cannot be instantiated. But I was going through the anonymous class explanation in the Java API and found an example which includes creating the object of an interface. How is this possible?
Part of the code:

```
public class HelloWorldAnonymousClasses {

interface HelloWorld {
 public void greet();
 public void greetSomeone(String someone); 
 }

 public void sayHello() {

class EnglishGreeting implements HelloWorld {

}

HelloWorld englishGreeting = new EnglishGreeting(); //object 1

HelloWorld frenchGreeting = new HelloWorld() {

String name = "tout le monde"; public void greet() { greetSomeone("mundo");} 
public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
name = someone; System.out.println("Hola, " + name);} }};
```

Object `englishGreeting` is fine since the object type is of interface `HelloWorld` but the reference goes to object type `EnglishGreeting`.

- Now the problem is about object `frenchGreeting`. How can this be valid since it creates `HelloWorld` object and `HelloWorld` is an interface. How can a interface type be instantiated. I couldn't find a solution supporting this example. Are we allowed to instantiate inner interfaces?
- Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: `frenchGreeting` reference goes to the object of anonymous type. You can see this types in the `bin` folder (with compiled classes).

Comment: This is an anonymous inner class, so it is actually a class and not an interface. True to form in Java, interfaces cannot be instantiated

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation..may be posting an answer would work?...Because I couldn't find anything related to this on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by all means allowed.
By doing `new HelloWorld { /*abstracted methods here*/ }` you are not creating an instance of the interface, but rather an anonymous class that's implementing the interface itself.
The same result can be achieved by creating a separate class that implements the interface, ex:

```
public class HelloWorldImplementation implements HelloWorld {
    /*abstracted methods here*/
}
```

Comment: Does that mean...this is a fixed syntax by which an anonymous class implements interface?

Comment: and if `HelloWorld` was a regular class,would that syntax mean that the anonymous class is `extending` HelloWorld?

Comment: @MathewsMathai you can always think of it like that. When I started learning I always thought to my self `new AnonymousClass implements SomeInterface`

Comment: @MathewsMathai  the anonymous class **implements** HelloWorld interface.

Comment: @MathewsMathai the principals for classes and interfaces are not the same. If you instantiate a regular class, there is no anonymous class involved. On the other hand if you instantiate an abstract class (for example), there is an anonymous class because there is abstraction involved.

Answer (score 2):

It is not creating an instance of the interface, it is creating an instance of an `anonymous class` that implements the **HelloWorld** `interface`.

If you compile the code using javac, you will see that the compiler will generate class file for the `anonymous class` which looks like

```
 HelloWorld$1.class
```

Now, if you decompile the generated class file using `javap` you will see that it implements **HelloWorld**

Comment: `new Helloworld() ` allocating memory for an HellowWorld object..right?

Comment: Can you add a bit of detailed explanation?..Because I couldn't find it anywhere on the net.

Comment: @MathewsMathai new HellowWorld() is just a normal object, it allocates memory. Nothing special about it

Comment: Consider `HelloWorld` as a regular class...in thay case `new HelloWorld()` would mean allocating memory for object of type HelloWorld() right??

Comment: @MathewsMathai sorry, but I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: It allocates memory for an object of an anonymous class implementing the HelloWorld interface. The syntax for anonymous classes is defined at the page you linked,  few lines later: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#syntax-of-anonymous-classes

Comment: Okay.I think I got it a little bit.My question was what is the meaning of `new someclass()`?Does this mean allocating memory for an object of type someclass? @Thomas Kläger

Answer (score 0):

May be this example helps you.

```
public interface IFoo
{

}

IFoo foo = new IFoo {

};
```

`foo` refers to the memory of empty object of type IFoo.